# Calculate a fitting text size

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to calculate the size my Font needs, so my text will be displayed fully in one line without clipping.

Example

> |-100px---HERE'S MY TEXT---100px-|

I have the DPI and all there stuff. Testing isn't a way, I am using Libgdx and the text ist display with an Button (Scene2D ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `BitmapFont.getBounds()`. The `TextBounds` it returns will tell you what you need. You can try a medium font, the go up or down based on how big or small the bounds are. I use this method to help scale UI sizes from old Droid 1s up to the new HD displays.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html